# Need to Escape some special characters which are present between XML Tags(<,>,') in java

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have a XML string which is already there in the database but while parsing this XML string I am getting Parsing issue because I have special characters like (<,>,') between XML tags.

I have used API called as StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml but it will escape the xml tags also .I dont want to escape the xml tags.I want to escape only the tag values.

Following is my xml string:-

```
<start>
<attribute name="resourcePageCategory"> <"there 'is' no category"></attribute>
<attribute name="resourceType" />
<attribute name="fairMarketValue">1000</attribute>
<attribute name="transferReason" />
<attribute name="effectiveDate" />
<attribute name="amountOwed">10</attribute>
</start>
```

Expected output should be like:-

```
<start>
    <attribute name="resourcePageCategory">  &lt; &quot;there &apos;is&apos; no category&quot;&gt;</attribute>
    <attribute name="resourceType" />
    <attribute name="fairMarketValue">1000</attribute>
    <attribute name="transferReason" />
    <attribute name="effectiveDate" />
    <attribute name="amountOwed">10</attribute>
    </start>
```

Basically it should escape the XML special charaters which are present between  xml tags because In my code I am sending this xml for parsing 
Please give me any sample code to do this.
It is good if I have any regular expression pattern which I can use in replaceAll method of a String.

And also note that the data is stored as xml string  in the database.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: What have yout tried so far?

Comment: Expected output should be <"there 'is' no category"> the special character like <,",> should be treated has  < - &lt;
    > - &gt;
    " - &quot

before parsing in xml

Comment: How is it stored in db?

Comment: It is stored in XML format

Comment: ".. because I have special characters like (<,>,') between XML tags" — then your stored files contain errors and are not *well-formed*. Generally speaking, XML tools can only process well-formed XML.

Comment: Hi Jongware ,the data is legacy data.So I can't change the data

Comment: Can you list all valid XML tags, and do those tag names appear in your xml content (outside of being valid tags)?

Comment: That does not change the fact that (generally speaking) XML tools can only process well-formed XML. You need to write some custom code that does not touch the specific tags that need to stay, but fixes the rest. If the files are not properly tagged, you should repair that as well.

Comment: valid xml tags are <start></start><attribute></attribute>:- In content It may appears also.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String repair(String xml) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<attribute name=\"[^\"]+\">)(.*?)(</attribute>)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(xml);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(xml.length() + xml.length() / 32);
    while (m.find()) {
        String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(m.group(2));
        m.appendReplacement(buf, m.group(1) + escaped + m.group(3));
    }
    m.appendTail(buf);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

The `.*?` momentarily does not allow line breaks, add DOTALL for that, and is eager (`?`) so two attributes on the same line are indeed taken as two.

Comment: Hi Joop,Thanks a million it works for me.